# ¿Algo parecido a XAMPP para usar con Electron?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, electron

Mi idea es crear un *Crud* local con bases de datos relacionales.

El programa *SQL Express* me permite crear un servidor y conectarme a una base de datos existente.

¿Existe alguna alternativa para que el mismo *Express*, sirva una base de datos *SQL*? o ¿Existe otro módulo que cree una base de datos en el servidor?

Lo más cercano que encontré es *PostgreSQL*. ¿Existe alguna forma de hacer que este corra dentro de *Electron* (es un ejecutable)?

Notas:

1. He estado usando ***sql.js*** como base de datos local pero estoy teniendo problemas por la cantidad de registros.
2. He leído acerca de bases de datos *NoSQL* como *MongoDB* y no me gusta el hecho de que no tengan llaves foráneas.

Answer (score 4):

> Mi idea es crear un CRUD local con base de datos relacional

Electron es una plataforma agnóstica, puedes usar SQLite, PostgreSQL y MySQL, incluso MongoDB. Un claro ejemplo es [SQLElectron](https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-gui), el cual puede conectarse a PostgreSQL y MySQL.

Si quieres una base de datos embebida, puedes usar SQLite, el paquete que te recomiendo es [sqlite](https://npmjs.com/package/sqlite). SQLite te permite almacenar gran cantidad de datos y consultar con muchas funciones SQL estándar. La principal contra que tiene es que no es buena para concurrencia por el hecho que [soporta solo una transacción a la vez](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html), es decir, si una transacción se está llevando a cabo otra no puede ejecutarse en simultáneo ya que la base de datos quedará cerrada (locked) hasta que la transacción acabe; sin embargo, en aplicaciones pequeñas como CRUDs o móviles, es una opción bastante acertada.

> No me gusta el hecho que MongoDB no tenga llave foránea.

No tiene por qué tenerla ya que MongoDB es una base de datos NoSQL orientada a documentos. Sin embargo, puedes tener documentos anidados o  [referencias](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/) entre ellos (asociaciones).

Hay implementaciones de base de datos orientadas a documentos para uso embebido como es el caso de [minimongo](https://github.com/mWater/minimongo). El hecho de escoger entre uno u otro tipo de base de datos es enteramente de diseño; si la integridad de datos es primordial y debe ser bien estructurada y normalizada, entonces una base de datos SQL sería la opción más acertada; si por el contrario no es requisito que la data sea estructurada pero sí lo es que la velocidad de comunicación sea muy rápida, entonces una base de datos NoSQL como MongoDB será la mejor opción. Conforme pruebes alternativas, irás dándote cuenta de los pros y contras.

Comment: Si conozco sqlite pero por lo que vi hace falta seguir unos pasos para que funcione correctamente en electron y algunos recomendaban usar sql.js en su lugar ya que es sqlite, pero escrito en javascript. Como mencioné tube algunos problemas (hacian referencia a la memoria) por lo que decidi buscar una alternativa antes de ir a las base de datos NoSQL que parece son las unicas que se ocupan en casos de bases de datos embebidas.

Comment: ¿Podrías decir qué problemas tienes usando SQLite en Electron?

Comment: No he utilizado sqlite, si sql.js y el problema exacto no lo recuerdo. En todo caso si no encuentro nada como lo que busco, intentaré con sqlite o sql.js y abrire otro tema si esque no encuentro una solución.